# JQuery attr('class') not fetching classname in Mozilla as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

I have class name like `emailList unread` like below

```
<tr class="emailList unread">
```

Using jQuery's `attr('class')` in chrome, it is fetching `emailList unread` but Mozilla fetches only `emailList`.
Any way to retrieve both the class names in Mozilla?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle??

Comment: Mozilla 37 returns me both class!

Comment: same here. i got all class on that element

Comment: I just created a fiddle, its returning both class names but in my application, it is not...might be some problem with event binding, i am confused now????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `className` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)) which will return something like what I think you're expecting from jQuery.

```
element.className // "emailList unread"
```

There is also `classList` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), note this doesn't work on IE < 10)

```
element.classList // ["emailList", "unread"]
```

If you have a jQuery object and need to get a DOM node you can use:

```
$jQObj.get(0).classList
$jQObj[0].classList
```

Comment: This is not available in every browser.

Comment: It is from IE10 (basic support which just means you can't use toggle)

Comment: Which still doesn’t include every browser, as I said.

Comment: thanx for the solution, but I solved it, had to use async: false